# mod re write help - WAMP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

Looking to re write a url in WAMP. I have AllowOverride Al (conf file). The mod rewrite modules is loaded. I am working on localhost

What i want to acheive is that on login the user gets redirected

localhost/propcms/xxxxxxx/

the actual address is

localhost/propcms/status.php?id=xxxxxxx

the .htaccess file has the following (and is located in localhost/propcms/ )

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /propcms/
RewriteRule ^propcms/([^/]*)/$ /propcms/status.php?id=$1 [L]
```

this is what i get....The requested URL /propcms/test121/ was not found on this server.

any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are specifying a rewritebase, you should not include it in your rewrite rule:

Try this snippet :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /propcms/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /propcms/status.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: hey it works however however now i hav another problem all the css files / js files being called within the status.php page seem to be now calling http://localhost/propcms/test121/css/bootstrap.css" instead of http://localhost/propcms/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: Had this problem once, the easy fix for me was to refer to my all my assets (js, images, css) with absolute path. 

Adding RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC] would make sure these type of file don't go through the same rewrite rules

Comment: <base href="//localhost/mywebsite/" />  - this is how i solved it... seems to work now i have to see if it works right across...